# how to redirect return to same page after POST in this case. django

Tags: python, django

I am creating this project in django. I am working on recording Add the number of products by BARCOD , where I go to a product -detail view, then hit the product link.  Add the number of product in form Everything works fine, but there is one thing. After add number of products by BARCOD I get sent back to a random(?) ....but I would like to stay on the same page Add the number of product in form . But how???
views

```
def returnitm_PK(request,item_PK_id):
    clientR=ClientPK.objects.get(place=request.POST.get("clientR"))
    item_PK=StockPK.objects.get(pk=item_PK_id)
    quan_BARCOD=request.POST.get("quan_BARCOD")
    Ear_number=request.POST.get("Ear_number")
    transaction=TransactionPK(item_PK=item_PK,clientR=clientR,quan_BARCOD=quan_BARCOD,Ear_number=Ear_number)
    transaction.save()

    if quan_BARCOD== '0009478908' :
        item_PK.R1=item_PK.R1+int(1)
    if quan_BARCOD== '0005663140' :
        item_PK.R2=item_PK.R2+int(1)
    item_PK.save()
    context = {'transaction':transaction,'item_PK':item_PK,'clientR':clientR,
                'quan_BARCOD':quan_BARCOD,'Ear_number':Ear_number,   }

    return render(request, "details_PK", context)
```

urls

```
    path('F_add_items/',views.F_add_items,name='F_add_items.html'),
    path('F_list_history/', views.F_list_history, name='F_list_history.html'),
    path('F_list_item/', views.F_list_item, name='F_list_item'),
    path('<int:item_PK_id>/details',views.details_PK,name='details_PK'),
    path('<int:item_id>/',views.details,name='details'),
    path('<int:item_id>/transfer',views.transferitm,name='transferitm'),
    path('<int:item_id>/returnitm',views.returnitm,name='returnitm'),
###############################################################################
    path('F_add_PK/',views.F_add_PK,name='F_add_PK.html'),
    path('F_list_history_PK/', views.F_list_history_PK, name='F_list_history_PK.html'),
    path('F_list_item_PK/', views.F_list_item_PK, name='F_list_item_PK'),
    path('<int:item_PK_id>/returnitm_PK',views.returnitm_PK,name='returnitm_PK'),
```

details_PK

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<center>
<div class="card" style="width: 50rem;">
<div class="card-body">

<form action="returnitm_PK" method="POST" >
    <div class="card-header">add {{ item.name }}</div>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="{{ item.name }}">

    
<div class="form-group">
<label for="clientR">clientR</label>
<select name="clientR" class="form-control" id="client">
{% for clientR in ClientPKs %}
<option value="{{ clientR.place }}">{{ clientR.place }}</option>
{% endfor %}

</select>
</div>

<!-- 
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Ear_number">رقم الاذن</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="0" id="Ear_number" name="Ear_number" min="1"/> 
</div>
                        -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="quan_BARCOD">quan_BARCOD</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="" id="quan_BARCOD" name="quan_BARCOD" min="0" max="9999999999"/> 
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add">
</form>
</div>
</div>

</center>


{% endblock %}
```

F_list_history_PK

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#example').DataTable();
            } );
    </script>

    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered display" style="width:100%">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>COUNT</th>
                        <th>num</th>
                        <th>category</th>
                        <th>BARCOD</th>
                        <th>28</th>
                        <th>30</th>
                        <th>32</th>
                        <th>34</th>
                        <th>36</th>
                        <th>38</th>
                        <th>color</th>
                        <th>TIMESTAMP</th>
                
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for item in items_list %}
        <tr>
                <td>{{ item.item_PK_id }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'details_PK' item.item_PK_id %}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.BARCOD }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.R1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.R2 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.R3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.R4 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.R5 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.R6 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.color }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.timestamp }}</td>
        </tr>    
    {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>COUNT</th>
                        <th>num</th>
                        <th>category</th>
                        <th>BARCOD</th>
                        <th>R1</th>
                        <th>R2</th>
                        <th>R3</th>
                        <th>R4</th>
                        <th>R5</th>
                        <th>R6</th>
                        <th>color</th>
                        <th>TIMESTAMP</th>
                    </tr>
            </tfoot>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what exactly you mean.  What view do you want to go to in each case?  In general, the way to handle something like this would be:

```py
def returnitm_PK(request,item_PK_id):

    clientR=ClientPK.objects.get(place=request.POST.get("clientR"))
    item_PK=StockPK.objects.get(pk=item_PK_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        quan_BARCOD=request.POST.get("quan_BARCOD")
        Ear_number=request.POST.get("Ear_number")
        transaction=TransactionPK(item_PK=item_PK,clientR=clientR,quan_BARCOD=quan_BARCOD,Ear_number=Ear_number)
        transaction.save()

        if quan_BARCOD== '0009478908' :
            item_PK.R1=item_PK.R1+int(1)
        if quan_BARCOD== '0005663140' :
            item_PK.R2=item_PK.R2+int(1)
        item_PK.save()
        
        return redirect('returnitm_PK', item.item_PK_id )
    
    context = {'transaction':transaction,'item_PK':item_PK,'clientR':clientR,
                'quan_BARCOD':quan_BARCOD,'Ear_number':Ear_number,   }

    return render(request, "details_PK", context)
```

And in your html:

```html
    <form action="{% url 'returnitm_PK' item.item_PK_id %}" method="POST" >
        <div class="card-header">add {{ item.name }}</div>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="item" value="{{ item.name }}">
    ...
```

Comment: I want to stay on the same page after pressing the  button POST, The extension for this page is <a href="{% url 'details_PK' item.item_PK_id %}">{{ item.name }}</a>. How can I write this in  . return redirect(' ') .

Comment: I updated the answer.  I *think* this is what you want.  Apologies if I still misunderstand.